# Bootstrap 3 blocking styling of disabled select in IE11

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to change the foreground text color of a disabled `select` in IE11.

I have an example where it [is working](http://jsfiddle.net/Vaccano/x1su3wbo/) (in IE11) with only plain HTML and CSS.

The key part there is this code:

```
select:disabled { color: green !important; }
```

But, then I add in Bootstrap 3 ([but keep my code the same](https://jsfiddle.net/Vaccano/5h25v2ua/)) :

- In Chrome and Firefox, the color stays changed.
- In IE11, the addition of bootstrap 3 causes the foreground to go back to a "hard to read gray".  (Something in the `btn` bootstrap style seems to cause this.)

**Is there a way to get Bootstrap 3 to not force the select disabled color to be grey in IE11?**

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<style>
        @media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none)
         {
         select:disabled { color: green !important; } /* IE10 */
         *::-ms-backdrop, select:disabled { color: green !important; } /* IE11 */
         }
</style>
```

Comment: Did not seem to have any effect.  If you were able to get the jsfiddle to work with it, can you share it?

Comment: If you remove comma after *::-ms-backdrop does working? Try put something like :root before the IE specific selectors sometime fixes the problems as well.

Comment: For sure is not a cache problem from server/browser? I do not have IE11 but I emulate browser to IE 11 and your code working in IE 11: https://postimg.org/image/nzjedhzpz/. Or .btn from Bootstrap override your code.

Comment: I can't seem to make it work. Can you try with this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Vaccano/5h25v2ua/ and see if it works for you?

Comment: I use your fiddle in emulation with IE11 and for me it works: https://postimg.org/image/6o9fe79c5/. Is a cached problem or .btn override your code(inspect entire css on that page).

Comment: You say you ran it "in emulation". What does that mean?  Are you really using IE11?  Or an emulator?  (My cache is clean and we are both loading the same page. )